# ¿Cómo reasignar una variable de una función?

Tags: python, alcance

Hice una función, que devolvería una variable. La var se llama "nombrearch", lo que hago es:

```py
def funcionDemostracion():
    nombrearch = "Prueba"
    return nombrearch
nombrearch = "Prueba2" # Aca no me deja acceder a la var y me da error
```

¿Cómo hago para poder modificar `nombrearch` luego de la función?

Comment: No me deja acceder a la var y cuando lo ejecuto me dice que no esta declarada

Comment: Exacto, pero lo que yo estoy queriendo hacer ahi es modificar la variable, ESO es lo que no me deja y no se como hacerlo

Comment: Bueno disculpa, pero ahora mismo lo que quiero hacer es lo mismo que te he dicho, modificar la variable luego de declarar la funcion

Comment: Primero llama a la función, esto te retorna un valor, ahora ya puedes hacer lo que sea con el valor retornado. Si quieres modificar el valor de la variable dentro de la función entonces investiga sobre el scope :D

Comment: Ok gracias!!!!!!

Comment: Esta es una pregunta de alcance de variable y no de el return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De esta forma puedes obtener el valor de la variable e ir modificandola fuera de la función:

```
def funcionDemostracion():
    nombrearch = "Prueba"
    return nombrearch

''' la variable nombrearch ahora vale "prueba" '''
nombrearch = funcionDemostracion()

'''print(nombrearch)'''
```

Y si lo que necesitas es una variable con alcance global, simplemente declarala de la siguiente forma:

```
global nombrearch

nombreArch = "Prueba"
```

Comment: Hola, intento declarar esa global y no me deja, me tira error, el error es que me dice que esta mal que este usando el = (estoy usando VS Code)

Comment: '''Declaramos la variable global sin contenido alguno'''
global miVar

miVar = "este será el contenido de la variable global"

Comment: Gracias!!! Ahora si ha funcionado!! Te debo una! Muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que hay dos variables `nombrearch` distintas. Una existe sólo dentro de la función `funcionDemostracion`. La otra existe fuera, a nivel de módulo.

```
def funcionDemostracion():
    nombrearch = "Prueba"  # Variable interna, desaparece al return
    return nombrearch
nombrearch = "Prueba2"     # Variable global, existe siempre.
```

Cuando ejecutas la función `funcionDemostracion`, se crea dentro de ella la variable `nombrearch`, pero desaparece tan pronto ejecutas el `return`. Por tanto, no tiene sentido intentar modificarla, pues ya no existe.

Esto tiene una razón: dentro de una función puedes usar nombres de variable sin importar que los mismos nombres se usen dentro de otras funciones.

Si quieres modificar el comportamiento de una función, tienes que hacerlo pasando un parámetro que controle ese comportamiento.

**Variables globales**

Dentro de una función, si quieres **usar** una variable global, basta con mencionarla

```
varnombre = "Juan"

def mostrar():
    print(varnombre) # -> Juan.
```

Si quieres **asignarla**, tienes que declararla `global`:

```
varnombre = "Juan"

def cambia_nombre():
    global varnombre
    varnombre = "Pedro"

cambia_nombre()
print(varnombre) # -> Pedro
```

Si no la declaras `global`, Python creará una variable local dentro de la función:

```
varnombre = "Juan"

def cambia_nombre():
    varnombre = "Pedro"

cambia_nombre()
print(varnombre) # -> Juan
```